# $(f(x))^p\neq f(x^p)$ on infinite field of characteristic $p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

It is easy to prove that if $f(x)\in\mathbb{Z}_p[x]$ then $(f(x))^p=f(x^p)$.

Now, I want to show that this may be false if $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is replaced by an infinite field of characteristic $p$. The only infinite field of characteristic $p$ I know is $K:=Frac(\mathbb{Z}_p[x])$.

So, I want to find $f(x)\in K[x]$ such that $(f(x))^p\neq f(x^p)$.

This seems pretty difficult to me. I mean, any $f(x)\in K[x]$ is a polynomial whose coefficients are fractions of polynomials whose coefficients are in $\mathbb{Z}_p$.

Do anyone see an easy way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Better to use $K[y]$ since otherwise you are going to have trouble determining which $x$ is which.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually this can be false in any field $F$ of characteristic $p$ with $|F|>p$. First, note that there is $\alpha \in F$ such that $\alpha^p \neq \alpha$: if not, the nonzero polynomial $f=x^p-x$ with degree $p$ has $|F|>p$ roots, a contradiction. Now just take $f(x)=\alpha x +1$. Then $f(x)^p=\alpha^px^p+1$ but $f(x^p)=\alpha x^p+1$.

Comment: Wow, this is awesome. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $\Bbb F_4 = \{0,1,u,u+1\}$, where $u^2 + u + 1 = 0$, of characteristic $2$.

In $\Bbb F_4[x]$, we can take $f(x) = ux^2$, and we have:

$f(x^2) = ux^4$, while $(f(x))^2 = u^2x^4$. But $u^2 = u+1 \neq u$.